# What does the "$\exists !$" modified quantifier mean in mathematical proof? eg, "$\exists\ !x \ P(x)$"

Tags: proof-writing, notation

I'm going through a book on mathematical proof and I recently read

> In this section we consider proofs in which the goal has the form $\exists\ !x \ P(x)$.

It then proceeds to define this statement as $\exists x(P(x) \land \neg \exists y(P(y) \land y \neq x))$.

What exactly does the "$\exists !$" modified quantifier mean in mathematical proof? Based on the context, I assume it means that $x$ is unique in some way.

Comment: $\exists\ !$ -- "exists unique"

Comment: "that $x$ is unique in some way" - no, uniqueness means "in only one way", not in some way.

Comment: @DietrichBurde This may be a language barrier: the OP means "in-some-way(-or-another) unique", in this case viz. $P$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, I agree. I meant his language. One should not  use "in some way" (or another) here.

Comment: It is a shorthand, because it is a common form, and the longer form in first order theory is heavily redundant.

Comment: $!$ is not an operator. $\exists!$ (or sometimes $\exists_!$) is a modified quantifier.

Comment: If you're reading How To Prove It, this notation is introduced in Section 2.2, right after example 2.2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though there is a good answer I want to add some comments.

$\exists!$ is used to denote the *unique existence* of some mathematical object. $\exists!x: P(x)$ is a shorthand for

$$
\exists x: [P(x) \land \forall y: (P(y) \Rightarrow x = y)]
$$

and we say there is unique $x$ that satisfies $P$.
It can be easily shown that this is equivalent to your statement using the [DeMorgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Extension_to_predicate_and_modal_logic).

There are several useful equivalent expressions.

1. $ \exists x: P(x) \land \forall x \forall y: [(P(x) \land P(y)) \Rightarrow x = y] $
   We read $\exists x: P(x)$ as there is *at least one* $x$ such that $P(x)$, and read the second sentence as any two elements that satisfy $P$ are identical, that is, there is *at most one* such $x$. This is useful when you already show that $P(x)$ and still want to show that such $x$ is unique afterward.
2. $\exists x \forall y: [P(y) \Leftrightarrow y = x]$
   This is sometimes used for brevity.

Reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification#Reduction_to_ordinary_existential_and_universal_quantification)

Answer (score 2):

$\exists ! \ x$ means that there exists a unique $x$ that satisfies whatever you're given about it.

If you want, you can find a (large) list of common math symbols on websites like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_mathematical_symbols). In your case, the one you were searching for is in the "Basic Logic" section.

Comment: $\exists !$ is not on that list on the site you provided, and under logic symbols, there is $!$ which reads "negation" which has nothing to do with $\exists !$. Overall not very good site. It says "ppm" means "per million" when it should be "parts per million", their root symbols and others look weird... I could go on.

Comment: @DavidP you're right, I had already used this website, but I did not notice the errors, I replaced the link with the related Wikipedia page, which does seem correct. Thanks for the comment